# Recognition and counting of books from side using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Just wish to receive some ideas on I can solve this problem.

For a clearer picture, here are examples of some of the image that we are looking at:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried looking into thresholding it, like otsu, blobbing it, etc. However, I am still unable to segment out the books and count them properly. Hardcover is easy of course, as the cover clearly separates the books, but when it comes to softcover, I have not been able to successfully count the number of books.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what I can do? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a sobel edge detector and used Hough transform to detect lines on the last image and it seemed to be working okay for me. You can then link the edges on the output of the sobel edge detector and then count the number of horizontal lines. Or, you can do the same on the output of the lines detected using Hough.

You can further narrow down the area of interest by converting the image into a binary image. The outputs of all of these operators can be seen in following figure ( I couldn't upload an image so had to host it here) http://www.pictureshoster.com/files/v34h8hvvv1no4x13ng6c.jpg

Refer to http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/analyzing-images.html#f11-12512 for some more useful examples on how to do edge, line and corner detection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I have already tried Hough Transform to detect lines before posting this question, albeit, this is not ideal as when the side of the books have words, for instance, the first image, lines will be detected over the words. While changing the parameters do help solve that, it will cause problems in the 3rd image where the middle book is not detected. Now I am looking for a new method or a way to counter the problem when using the hough transform. Any idea? But +1 vote anyway(: Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that @audiohead's recommendation is good but you should be careful when applying the Hough transform for images that will have the library's stamp as it might confuse it with another book (You can see that the letters form some break-lines that will be detected by `sobel`).

Consider to apply first an edge preserving smoothing algorithm such as a `Bilateral Filter`. When tuned correctly (setting of the Kernels) it can avoid these such of problems.

**A Different Solution That Might Work (But can be slow)**

Here is a different approach that is based on pixel marking strategy.

a) Based on some very dark threshold, mark all black pixels as `visited`.

b) While there are `unvisited` pixels: Pick the next `unvisited` pixel and apply a region-growing algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing while marking its pixels with a unique number. At this stage you will need to analyse the geometric shape that this region is forming. A good criteria to detecting a book is that the region is creating some form of a rectangle where width >> height. This will detect a book and mark all its pixels to the unique number.

Once there are no more unvisited pixels, the number of unique numbers is the number of books you will have + For each pixel on your image you will now to which book does it belongs.

Comment: Yup. agreed, I have actually explored audiohead recommendation before posting this questions, actually tried quite a number of methods in addition to that. Instead of using Bilateral like you suggested, I used pyrmeanshiftfiltering instead when trying the HoughLine transform, but new problem arises from tat:/ (hardcover books)

Comment: I like the idea of your pixel marking strategy/region growing method, sounds like it will work if I merge it with some of my other methods. Let me try and get back to you if it's successful. Give a day or 2 though(: Thanks a ton for that suggestion. (:

Comment: as promised, here is my update:The solution is not robust enough, especially for 2 softcover books stacked together. This is because the line separating the 2 books are not visible enough in some of the images that I tried on. Works once in awhile though. I think I try see if I can overcome the problem I face while trying your region growing method.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. In your region growing method, what was your stop criteria ? Did you make the stop criteria based on the starting pixel or based on the neighbourhood of the discovered pixel ?

Comment: I used it based on the neighbourhood of the discovered pixel.

Comment: the neighbourhood of two adjacent softcover pages is very similar and if you put on top of that some illumination problems it will be very difficult. Perhaps you should consider to maintain some median value while discovering new pixels and use it as a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to keep the books this way? If you can change the books to face back side to the camera then I think you can get more information about the different colors used by different books.The lines by Hough transform or edge detection will be more prominent this way.

Comment: Yup, I wish to keep the books this way for now, I have done book spines already, and is currently trying different layout of the books.

Answer (score 1):

There exist more sophisticated methods which are much better in contour detection and segmentation, you can have a look at them here, however it is quite slow, http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html

Once you get the ultrametric contour map, you can perform some computation on them to count the number of books

Answer (score 0):

I would try a completely different approach; with paperbacks, the covers are medium-dark lines whilst the rest of the (assuming white pages) are fairly white and "bloomed", so I'd try to thicken up the dark edges to make them easy to detect, then that would give the edges akin to working with hardbacks which you say you've done.

I'd try something like an erosion to thicken up the edges. This would be a nice, fast operation.